# Microsoft teams messaging extension inconsistently sending a valid conversation ID to use in a graph call

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I am developing a MSTeams application, and inside I use a messaging extension. Upon opening the extension, a request is fired over to my message handler, which I use an azure function to handle. Alongside the request is a payload, with details about the context (in this case the conversation or chat) of where the messaging extension was opened from.

Now, I've built up a graph URL with the conversation ID from the payload:

```js
const id = context.req.body.conversation.id
const graphEndpoint = encodeURIComponent(`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/chats/${id}/members`)
```

I authenticate a user by calling `microsoftTeams.authentication.authenticate({...})` before I make the call, and use the token in the request.

Sometimes, this call will succeed, and return the information I want. However, the other times it will fail with a 400, telling me I had a bad request, despite it being a GET request with no body.

I notice in bad requests, that the conversation ID doesn't trail with `@thread.v2` or `@unq.gbl.spaces` etc. I have no clue why this is so inconsistent, or if it's my fault. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I have also seen that the issue only occurs when the id starts with `a:`, and succeeds when it starts with `19:`. However, the context in which I open the messaging extension is the same each time: In a 1:1 / User:User chat.

I have previously implemented [installing the bot in the conversation to get this information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/messaging-extension-v3/create-extensions?tabs=typescript#request-to-install-your-conversational-bot), but this method is very undesirable. Perhaps a side point - it seems that the conversations where I have previously installed the bot seem to return the `19:` id, and everything else `a:`.

Here's an example of the 400 response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Bad Request",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2021-01-25T09:43:26",
      "request-id": "3bb55aa2-e694-4c80-952c-88842f482dc1",
      "client-request-id": "3bb55aa2-e694-4c80-952c-88842f482dc1"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the requestid, timestamp from the Graph API's response logs

Comment: @Dev I'll edit it in now 

Comment: @Kobe:
Could you please have a look on this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/conversationmember-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http&viewFallbackFrom=graph-rest-beta).

Comment: @Rama-MSFT I have read this documentation already. I understand how I should make the request, but the problem is how I unexpectedly receive a 200 OK at times and 400 Bad Request at other times. I am not using application permissions, but delegated.

Comment: @Kobe: Could you please let us know whether you are facing the issue only with external users?

Comment: @Rama-MSFT The issue is with all users - not limited to external users.

Comment: @Kobe - The conversation id you received in the turn-context is not the chat-id. The conversation id is different from conversation id. Conversation id the id between bot and the user and chat id the id of the chat. Both are different. You cannot use conversation id to call the graph API. Please use the chat id to call graph API. You can get the chat id using list [chats API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http).

Answer (score 0):

The conversation id you received in the turn-context is not the chat-id. The conversation id is different from conversation id. Conversation id the id between bot and the user and chat id the id of the chat. Both are different. You cannot use conversation id to call the graph API. Please use the chat id to call graph API. You can get the chat id using list [chats API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http).

Comment: I'll try giving this a go. What I don't understand is why sometimes, the conversation ID will work with the API, when you said it is different to the chat ID.

Comment: The whole purpose of my code is to get the users' names from a conversation, without having to add the bot to the conversation. Is this the only way to go about it? Or is there something more simple? I can't seem to find much documentation on it.